# Pattern Match symbols that begin with same letter?

Tags: pattern-matching

I want to pattern match all symbols beginning with $e$

```
{e1 x e2 y e3 z e4} /. lettersBeginningWithe -> 3
```

How can this be done in mathematica?

Comment: What should happen when `e1 = 2;` and `Hold[{e1 x e2 y e3 z e4}]` is the expression you want to search?

Comment: This can be useful to match generated symbols such as `Unique[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use [`SymbolName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymbolName.html) with [`StringStartsQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringStartsQ.html).

```
{e1 x e2 y e3 z e4} /. s_Symbol /; StringStartsQ["e"]@SymbolName[s] -> 3
(* {81 x y z} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

**Improvement Courtesy of Karsten. 7 (see comments)**

Just a way using `Pick`:

```
var = {e1 , x , e2, y, e3, z, e4};
Pick[var, StringTake[#, 1] & /@ (ToString /@ var), "e"]
```

**Improved:**

```
Pick[var, StringTake[ToString /@ var, 1], "e"]
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[var, _?(StringTake[ToString[#], 1] == "e" &)]
```

Using `StringMatchQ` (method is corrected by Alexey Popkov, see comments):

```
Pick[var, StringMatchQ[ToString[#], "e" ~~ ___] & /@ var]
```

**Improved:**

```
Pick[var, StringMatchQ[ToString /@ var, "e" ~~ ___]]
```

Comment: Quite excessive use of `/@` inside `Pick`. Unleash the full power and beauty of `Pick` by taking advantage of the `Listable` attribute: `Pick[var, StringTake[ToString /@ var, 1], "e"]` and `Pick[var, StringContainsQ[ToString /@ var, "e" ~~ _]]`.

Comment: @Karsten7. my bad habits die hard...and I have been too slow to recognize and apply the operator forms. :)

Comment: Note that `StringContainsQ["aer", "e" ~~ _]` returns `True` what isn't what you want. The correct test is `StringMatchQ["aer", "e" ~~ ___]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov yes as my comment, perhaps unintelligibly, warns and posits use of WordBoundary. I will edit when I get time. Taking my daughter to her home. If you wish to edit or modify please feel free with your own attribution.

Comment: @ubpdqn I've edited the answer and replaced `StringContainsQ` with correct method which uses `StringMatchQ`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thank you very much. I will try to do better...always opportunity to improve so thanks for vigilance :)

Answer (score 2):

```
MatchQ[e3, a_ /; First[Characters[ToString[a]]] === "e"]
```